# R dataframe rowwise operation

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to do a row-wise operation in R on a data frame.

I have an input similar to,

```
ID Location
100 SFO
100 NY
100 LV
101 Chicago
101 NJ
102 ABC
102 XYZ
102 RTE
102 EWR
```

Output should be

```
ID Location
100 SF0-
    NY-
    LV
101 Chicago-
    NJ
102 ABC-
    XYZ-
    RTE-
    EWR
```

Output should have one row for each ID with all locations concatenated separated by a delimiter and every new location should start on a new line. I export output directly to excel and send to end users.

Comment: That looks more like a csv file than a data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make a lot of sense: one ID for each row, but locations on a "different line". How are "different lines" not rows??

This converts to rows with the locations separated by `"-"`.

```
aggregate(Location~ID,df,paste,collapse="-")
#    ID        Location
# 1 100       SFO-NY-LV
# 2 101      Chicago-NJ
# 3 102 ABC-XYZ-RTE-EWR
```

This separates by `"-"` followed by newline.

```
aggregate(Location~ID,df,paste,collapse="-\n")
```